# Odoo search panel sorting

Tags: python, sorting, odoo

I need to sort custom search panel which displays projects list in alphabetical order. I need to display the project list by its creation date in Odoo community edition.

Here is the XML code:

```
<record id="project_task_search_panel_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.task.search.panel</field>
            <field name="model">project.task</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_search_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search position="inside">
                    <searchpanel>
                        <field name="project_id" enable_counters="1" icon="fa fa-user" group_by = "project_id" />
                    </searchpanel>
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>
```